# A Better way to rename XAML file class when renaming the file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

EDIT: The main issue when renaming the file is to rename xaml contents

My intuition is screaming that there is a better way to do this, but the following works, my question is to see if there a better or an already existing method that can do this

I have a small WPF app that loads xaml files and can be imported/edited and exported.
When the WPF app initialises it makes a placeholder xaml file that you can edit,
"StartingXamlFile.xaml" when exporting I used a `SaveFileDialog` and the user can change the name. But the contents of the XAML file is not changed according to the file name. Also when importing an existing XAMLfile then editing and exporting(changing name when exporting) the same thing occurs.

Solution:

I set up a Singleton object to hold the file name `XamlFile` with property content and path. Now the default is set to "StartingXamlFile" when importing this is replaced. This is done following [Gang of four Singleton technique](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Singleton.aspx)

SaveFile code that doesnt work:

```
 SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            dlg.FileName = "StartingXamlFile"; // Default file name
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".xaml"; // Default file extension
            dlg.Filter = "xaml files (*.xaml)|*.xaml|All files (*.*)|*.*"; // Filter files by extension

            // Show save file dialog box
            var result = dlg.ShowDialog();
            if (result == true)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(dlg.FileName, editedContent);
            }
```

Save File code that does work using `Replace`:

```
if (result == true)
            {
                var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dlg.FileName);
                var testing = XamlFile.Content.Replace(XamlFile.Path,name);
                File.WriteAllText(dlg.FileName, testing);
            }
```

Comment: `File.Copy()` and `File.Delete()` would get you there quite quickly with little overhead.

Comment: @Sinatr.. that does not rename the contents only the file name. Xaml files hold x:Class values that reference the file name

Comment: @JohnChris you way want to update the title of your question since you are not really asking how to rename an XAML file you are asking how to rename a class in an XAML file when renaming the file.

Comment: @Lithium Done, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give this question an accepted answer, I have not found a better way to this other than:

```
SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            dlg.FileName = "StartingXamlFile"; // Default file name
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".xaml"; // Default file extension
            dlg.Filter = "xaml files (*.xaml)|*.xaml|All files (*.*)|*.*"; 

            // Show save file dialog box
            var result = dlg.ShowDialog();
            if (result == true)
            {
        //X:Class replacement is done here
               var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dlg.FileName);
               var testing = XamlFile.Content.Replace(XamlFile.Path,name); 
               File.WriteAllText(dlg.FileName, testing);
            }
```

XamlFile is a singleton object that contains the content of the xaml 
and initial name of file when starting up or importing, so when you export it 
replaces all references to the initial name